# Joomla 3 user_usergroup_map table set a group_id=9 after registration

Tags: php, joomla

I encountered a problem in joomla 3.

When I registered in my site a name, username and email and then after that it was redirected to the page I wanted but my problem is the `user_usergroup_map` table set a `group_id=9` after registration.

Can you tell me where this happenning and can I changed the value of 9 to 2 upon registration?

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This question is about Joomla specific implementation details, you may get a better result if you, try asking on [the Joomla Q&A StackExhange site](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I found the solution make sure your $_POST are have $_POST["groups"] = array(2); 2 is the value of Registered